# DAX expression for COUNT of GROUPBY

Tags: sql, group-by, powerbi, dax

I am new to PowerBI and writing DAX expressions.

I have a table with a text column with different values.All I want to do is get the count for each distinct value. It's easily achieved with this SQL but I can't get the right DAX expression for it.

```
select [value],count(*) as TagCount from Tags
group by [value]
order by TagCount desc
```

Any help?

Answer (score 7):

You can do something similar in Power BI as follows:

```
SUMMARIZE(Tags, Tags[value], "TagCount", COUNT(Tags[value]))
```

or

```
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Tags[value], "TagCount", COUNT(Tags[value]))
```

---

You can also do this as a matrix visual with `Tags[value]` for the Rows and the measure `COUNT(Tags[value])` for the Values. You can then sort by whichever column you choose by clicking the column heading on the visual.

Comment: cool. thanks..that worked. Any idea how I can sort it in descending order of the count?

Comment: @alwayslearning Not sure the best way to do that at the table level, but it's easy if you want it in a visual. See my edit above.