# How to apply grouped result to VAR.S?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, dax

I'm new to DAX. I want to create a measure that groups the `Date` table by the same date, counts the numbers (result is like below `Count` table) and calculates the variance of counts.

[image: example]

With the help of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46084978/dax-expression-for-count-of-groupby), I am able to write the following DAX so as to transform `Date` table into `Count` table, but I can't figure out how `VAR.S` can be used with it. Can you help me? Thanks!

```
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Dates[Date], "DateCount", COUNT(Dates[Date]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I don't have to use pivot table and did it with Power Query.

```
SelectedColumns = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Date"}),
Grouped = Table.Group(SelectedColumns, {"Date"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}}),
TheStandardDeviation = List.StandardDeviation(Grouped[Count])
```